# How to serve data from HDFS fast/in realtime in my services?

Tags: hadoop, database-design, architecture, bigdata, data-warehouse

For now, in my company, every team that needs to serve data from HDFS to users creates own tool for that task.

We want to create a generic tool for fast/in real-time serving that data through HTTP from HDFS to my services. By generic I mean the tool should serve data only for my selected services added to the configuration and that should be the only action that users have to perform to use this generic tool. This new tool should be informed about new data that appeared in HDFS and then invoke some kind of job that moves data from HDFS to our fast storage.

Applications can update their data every day or every hour but every service can do it at different times (service A can be updated every day at 7 AM and service B can be updated every hour). I think we do not want to use any schemas and want to access our data using the only key and partition date. Querying is not necessary.

We do not know yet how much capacity or read/writes per second our tool needs to withstand.

We’ve worked some solution for our problem but we are interested if there are similar solutions in open source already or maybe any of you had a similar use case?
This is our proposal of architecture:
[architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zLUj.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to access HDFS over HTTP then WebHDFS might fit your use case. You could add a caching layer to speed up requests for hot files, but I think as long as you are using HDFS you'll never get sub-second response for any file that isn't already cached. You must decide if that is acceptable for you.

I'm unsure of how well WebHDFS works with huge files.

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.3/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/WebHDFS.html

Comment: Thanks, but not sub-second response for not cached files is not acceptable

Comment: Then you should not use HDFS.

Comment: I say that because your architecture is basically a giant cache of HDFS. Anything not cached will be slow.

Comment: Before you build that architecture, check out Centralized Cache Management in HDFS and also Hbase.